# how to import csv sheet to mysql database using php and html

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv

I want to import csv sheet to MYSQL database using HTML form,
now i can import successfully but the problem is, i have to give inputfile path in script only, so that user can upload the csv file and as soon as the file is uploaded, call the function and pass the ‘path of file’ as the parameter.
Below i tried this code,

```
 <?php
    $delimiter = ',';

    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'ProcessTrackingSystem');

    if (($handle = fopen("/var/www/html/new/database_template.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
       while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
         foreach($data as $i => $content) {
            $data[$i] = $db->real_escape_string($content);
         }
       $db->query("INSERT INTO ProcessTrackingSystem.ProcessDetails VALUES('" . implode("','", $data) . "');");
      }
      fclose($handle);
    }

  ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
   <title>Import a CSV File with PHP & MySQL</title>
</head>

<body>

   <?php 
      if (!empty($_GET[success])) { echo "<b>Your file has been imported. </b><br><br>"; } //generic success notice 
   ?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
  Choose your file: <br />
   <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" />
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

this script is taking input but we have to specify the path in code, help me to take user input.
thanks in advance.

Comment: off topic but are you ready to cleanse for level 2 sql injection attacks with mysqli?

Comment: i dont think so that its off topic

Comment: @AdityaK it is quite on topic in fact

Comment: I was being nice about it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I got desired output by below code,

```
<?php if (!$_POST) { ?>
<html>
        <body>
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Choose your file: <br /> 
        <input name="csv" type="file" id="csv" /> <br /> <br /> 
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" /> 
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
} else {
$connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ProcessTrackingSystem");
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) {
//get the csv file 
$file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$i = 0;
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    if ($i > 0) {
$import = ("INSERT INTO ProcessTrackingSystem.ProcessDetails VALUES('" . implode("','", $data) . "');");
        $connect->query($import);
    }
    $i++;
}
fclose($handle);
print "Import done";
}
}
?>
```

this code is providing user to upload csv file from web form.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have have a CSV file with following format and first column corresponding your field name:

```
column name1    column name2    column name3
Value1           Value2           Value3
Value4           Value5           Value6

<?
//Import uploaded file to Database
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r"); // Get File's data
$columnArray=array();//stores the column
$dataArray=array();//store all rows
$records=""//store the all records in string format
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) { //Get Excel sheet data row by row
        if($f==0){ //Store first row as column headings
            foreach ($data as $k=>$v){
                $columnArray[$k]=strtolower(str_replace(" ","_",$v));
            }
        }else{ 
            // Store insert string for payment record
            foreach ($data as $k=>$v){
                $dataArray[$f][$k]=$v;
                $records.="'".$v."',";
            }
            if($records!=""){
                $records.="'0',now()),(";
            }
        }
    $f++;
}
fclose($handle);//close file
if($records!=""){ // Insert payment record string
        $records=substr($records, 0, -3);
        $colStr=implode($columnArray,",");
        $insertQuery="INSERT INTO table_name (".$colStr.",checked,dateval) VALUES (".$records.")";
        $this->EbsPaymentDetail->query($insertQuery);
}
$n=0;
//Display table containing records imported 
$dataTable.= "<h2><strong>Following records has been successfully Imported !!</strong></h2><table width='100%'><tr><td><strong>S No.</strong></td>";
foreach ($columnArray as $k=>$v){
    $dataTable.= "<td><strong>".ucwords(str_replace("_"," ",$v))."</strong></td>";
}
$dataTable.= "</tr>";
foreach ($dataArray as $k=>$v){
    $dataTable.= "<tr>";
    $dataTable.= "<td>".++$n."</td>";
    for($j=0;$j<count($v);$j++){
        $dataTable.= "<td>".$v[$j]."</td>";
    }
    $dataTable.= "</tr>";
}
$dataTable.= "</table>";
?>
```